# Taking data from ASP.net webpage and inserting into SQL database

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, razor

I thought about taking data directly from the HTML forms, through javascript, or through the code behind of the page, but am not sure how to do any of these or which one is the most secure, scalable, and efficient (although I would presume using ASP.net/C# is the best option).  I need advice from someone who has done something like this before so I am not blindly going in and creating insecure databases or methods of manipulating the data.

Here is my insert query:

```
INSERT INTO customtable_ReviewsTable ([ItemCreatedBy]
, [ItemCreatedWhen]
, [ItemModifiedBy]
, [ItemModifiedWhen]
, [ItemOrder]
, [ItemGUID]
, [ReviewText]
, [Rating]
, [UserName]
, [SKUID] ) 
VALUES ( @ItemCreatedBy
, @ItemCreatedWhen
, @ItemModifiedBy
, @ItemModifiedWhen
, @ItemOrder
, @ItemGUID
, @ReviewText
, @Rating
, @UserName
, @SKUID); 

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [ItemID]
```

This query was created by the content management system I am using, and appears to be correct for my table name and field names.  I'm just going to assume it is correct or mostly correct.  For the curious, this is a product reviews database.

So now, I am stuck.  How do I create these variables on the ASP.net based web page, and feed them to the query?  For example, I honestly don't know where to place (in what code file or where in) that query.  Also, I don't understand where the query will pull those variables from.

My first thought was that the @var refer to the variables I will create on my page (using C# Razor).  This is only because I have seen that type of syntax before refer to Razor variables made on the page.  Obviously I could accomplish this also with the C# code behind as well.

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for are introductory tutorials to building ASP.NET web sites/applications.  There is a lot of information to get you started here: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: Well, basically you're asking for an explanation of the (basic) principles of ASP.NET... hard to answer here !

Comment: I finally found a good code example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720188(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Bear in mind though that link you posted is a VB.NET example and you mentioned C# in your question